# Calling a constructor with no parameters works, with a parameter doesn't. Why?

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a class defined as follows:

```
class Foo {

  private:
    boolean feature;

  public:
    Foo(boolean feature) : feature(feature) {}

  // ...
};
```

I'm trying to construct an instance, as a private property of another class:

```
class Bar {

  private:
    Foo foo(true);

    // ...
  };
```

This doesn't work. I get `expected identifier before numeric constant` on the line with the declaration. When I remove the parameter from `Foo`'s constructor definition simply and ask for a `Foo foo;`, it works.

Why?

How do I define and declare an instance of `Foo` that takes a boolean parameter?

Comment: move it to the initializer list

Comment: @user3528438: That's so last decade.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use that initialisation syntax in a class member declaration; you can only initialise members with `{}` or `=`. The following should work (assuming support for C++11 or later):

```
Foo foo{true};
Foo foo = Foo(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

The pre-C++11 way to do this is:

```
class Bar {
  public:
    Bar() : foo(true){} //initialization
  private:
    Foo foo; //no parameter
};
```

Bonus:

```
class Bar {
  private:
    Foo foo(); //<- This is a function declaration for a function
               //named foo that takes no parameters returning a Foo.
               //There is no Foo object declared here!
};
```